# Big Sur automatic hfs_convert to APFS STUCK at 10% on external rotational drive

Tags: macos, encryption, filevault, apfs, hfs+

So I have a 3TB external rotational drive that I only ever used with older macOS versions.

Big Sur then decided to automatically do a background hfs_convert to APFS on the external rotational drive which is now permanently STUCK at 10% encryption no matter what I have tried.

Even worse, after a few seconds of being mounted it then declares that it is fully filevault encrypted and refuses to decrypt.

All files are listed correctly in their directories but are inaccessible.

I did manage to trigger the encryption progress one time on another mac running Mojave but it was USB 2.0 and took a day to get to 14%. Upon putting it back on the Big Sur machine it's gone back to mounting at 10% for few seconds and then FileVault encrypted.

Have googled this extensively and tried everything I can find.

The most useful solutions were to use another mac, and also if it says 10% (Paused) to then copy a file onto the drive to get it started. These don't work anymore... perhaps the older machine remembers the drive?

Here are the errors I get when doing an fsck_apfs:

```
** Checking the container superblock.
   Checking the checkpoint with transaction ID 5023576.
** Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
** Checking the space manager.
** Checking the space manager free queue trees.
** Checking the object map.
** Checking volume.
** Checking the APFS volume superblock.
   The volume Elemental was formatted by hfs_convert (748.77.12) and last modified by apfs_kext (1677.120.9).
** Checking the object map.
error: ersb_total_blk_to_encrypt (681983560) exceeds bm_bit_count (366237179)
   Encryption Rolling data structures are invalid.
** The volume /dev/disk3s1 could not be verified completely.
```

Can I delete some checkpoints or snapshots for the volume?

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated! <--[mods don't remove, I am free to be appreciative]

P.S. I have no idea why on earth Apple decided it would be a good idea to automatically convert HFS+ encrypted volumes to APFS encrypted on large rotational drives with seemingly no warning. I have noticed in Big Sur Disk Utility that HFS+ Encrypted is no longer an option but that shouldn't mean auto background conversion rendering files inaccessible during conversion.